# Android Drag and Drop table / grid layout

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

Im on creating Drag and Drop feature. 
I have table layout with day-hours items ( 8.00, 9.00, 10.00 and so on...) is there any way to put item using drag'n'drop in both 8.00 and 9.00 rows ? but for example i want to put it by 8.30 and 9.15

Does anybody have an idea ?

Comment: Do you wanna use other libraries? You can find some drag-drop libs here https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.indianic.coslib

Comment: there's nothing useful for me :(